# How to dynamically set binding type's "formatOptions" and "constraints" in XML with binding?

Tags: binding, sapui5

I have a list of elements (OData set) and use a binding to show this list.
One field is for a quantity value and this value could sometimes need some decimal places.

The requirement is: only show that amount of decimal numbers that is also available in the OData service.

Annotation techniques can't be used.

I 'hacked' something that is misusing a formatter to update the type of a binding. But this is 'a hack' and it is not possible to convert it to XML views. (The reason is a different handling of the scope the formatter will be called).

So **I am searching for a working solution for XML views.**

The following code would **not** work but shows the issue:

> ```js
> new sap.m.Input({ // looking for an XML solution with bindings
>   value: {
>       path: "Quantity",
>       type: new sap.ui.model.type.Float({
>           // formatOptions
>           maxFractionDigits: "{QuantityDecimals}",
>           // ...
>       }, {
>           // constraints
>           minimum: 0
>       }),
>       // ...
>   }   
> });
> ```

The `maxFractionDigits : "{QuantityDecimals}"` should be "dynamic" and **not a constant value**.

Comment: Why not you create a formatter in XML?

Comment: I have not tested it but, I think, the same sytax with type:... can be used in XML as well. May be you can check this article: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3624765

Comment: The comments do not answer my question. The question is the "dynamic" handling of number of allowed floats. Assume you have a quantity field in a list. Sometimes you allow decimals (for KG or so) but most of the time it is not allowed because it must be a nattural number. The hack works because of JavaScript allows this. With XML view it is not possible this way.

Comment: @user3783327 Could you create an issue on GitHub? As described in my answer below..

Answer (score 2):

Setting `formatOptions` and `constraints` dynamically in XML (via bindings or a declared function) is unfortunately **not (yet) supported**. But IMHO this is a valid enhancement request that app developers would greatly benefit from, since it encourages declarative programming.

I already asked for the same feature some years ago but in a comment at https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2449#issuecomment-474304965 (See my answer to Frank's question *"If XMLViews would allow a way to specify the dynamic constraints as well (e.g. enhanced syntax), would that fix the problem?"*).

Please create a new issue via https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new with a clear description of what kind of problems the feature would resolve and possibly other use cases (You can add a link to my [comment](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2449#issuecomment-474304965)). I'll add my  to your GitHub issue, and hopefully others too.

---

I'll update this answer as soon as the feature is available.

Answer (score 0):

Get your dynamic number from your model and store it in a JS variable.

```
var nQuantityDecimals = this.getModel().getProperty("/QuantityDecimals");

new sap.m.Input({
    value : {
        path : "Quantity",
        type : new sap.ui.model.type.Float({
            maxFractionDigits : nQuantityDecimals,
            source : {
                groupingSeparator: ",",
                decimalSeparator: ".",
                groupingEnabled: false
            }
        }, {
            minimum:0
        })
    }   
}),
```

Comment: More or less my existing hack works like this, my problem is to have a JS view. And I would also be happy to avoid some strange ID handling to get a control in the controller.